# why must I use @Stateless in ejb? What happens if I don't use it?

Tags: ejb, stateless

In J2EE Java code, I can see following code

```
@Stateless
public class PostLabellingDao
    {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "tlga")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public void loadRecord(String sKey) throws Exception
        {
        JPAQuery jpaQuery = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
        QSomeEntity q = QSomeEntity.someEntity;

        List<SomeEntity> oList
            = jpaQuery
                .from(q)
                ).list(q);

        ... // some code on Database
```

If I remove @Stateless annotation, the application continue to work !

What is the **utility** of using `@Stateless` annotation ?

I know the difference between `@Stateful` and `@Stateless` and `@Singleton` but I search some explanations on `Why?` and `When?` using `@Stateless` to avoid using it when it is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

EJB configuration model is based on configuration by exception, so when you annotated a bean with @Stateless or @Stateful or @Singletone  many services will be activated for the bean such as transaction, security, thread safety and etc. so if you do not need these services. you must not annotate your bean with those annotations.

EJB 3 in action book have some good advice. such as(your case is third one):

> 1)if everything is a session bean, then performance will suffer due to
>   container overhead
>
> 2)Making utility classes session beans isn’t terribly
>   useful(A utility API should probably just use CDI and not EJB)
>
> 3) DAO/repository classes. Although these objects rely on thread safety
>   and transactions, they don’t need to be session beans themselves
>   because they’ll likely be used throughthe EJB application service
>   layer
>
> 4)you should not use EJBs directly as JSF-backing beans

Comment: if you vote for my question, I can vote up to your answer. Until now, it is impossible for me to vote up because my reputation is too low !

Comment: I think that you can click on checkbox, if the answer is ok in your opinion.